# MediaPlayer causes rendering problem in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer

When I create a MediaPlayer, using the code below, Android Studio keeps showing rendering problem

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview
fun TestScreen(){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val audio = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.testaudio1)
    Button(onClick = {audio.start()}) {
        Text(text = "play")
    }
}
```

the testaudio1 is an mp3 which I put in a newly made android resource directory in res

[res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvmHp.png)

The render problem is shown below

[render-problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUhO3.png)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you may need to make sure that your MediaPlayer is properly initialized and managed in a **background thread.**

Additionally, you may also need to make sure that you are using the correct context when creating the MediaPlayer object and that you are handling the lifecycle of the MediaPlayer correctly to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this render issue, too.

Only way around for me was using a virtual device.  No problems there.